# FreeRTOS - Restore Stackpointer for last function call

Tags: freertos, cortex-m

Freertos uses the code section below for fault handlers, to get information out of the current stack pointer (the task-stack which caused the crash). unfortunately this works only based on exceptions, and if the the causing function is the last call in the stack.

```
    "tst lr, #4                                                     \n"
    "ite eq                                                         \n"
    "mrseq r0, msp                                                  \n"
    "mrsne r0, psp                                                  \n"
    "ldr r1, ADDRESS                         \n"
    "bx r1                                                          \n"
    "ADDRESS: .word stackdump_printf   \n"
```

I am looking for the same idea of implementation as above, but with the ability to give me the stack info if the function causing the error was not the last caller, as in the example below

```
lumos_c_mangling void getRegistersFromStack( uint32_t *pulFaultStackAddress )
{
  uint32_t dummy;
  /* These are volatile to try and prevent the compiler/linker optimising them
     away as the variables never actually get used.  If the debugger won't show the
     values of the variables, make them global my moving their declaration outside
     of this function. */
  volatile uint32_t r0;
  volatile uint32_t r1;
  volatile uint32_t r2;
  volatile uint32_t r3;
  volatile uint32_t r12;
  volatile uint32_t lr; /* Link register. */
  volatile uint32_t pc; /* Program counter. */
  volatile uint32_t psr;/* Program status register. */

  r0 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 0 ];
  r1 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 1 ];
  r2 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 2 ];
  r3 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 3 ];

  r12 = pulFaultStackAddress[ 4 ];
  lr  = pulFaultStackAddress[ 5 ];
  pc  = pulFaultStackAddress[ 6 ];
  psr = pulFaultStackAddress[ 7 ];

  /* When the following line is hit, the variables contain the register values. */
  for(;;);
}

void Hardfault_Handler()
{
  __asm__
  (
      " tst lr, #4                                                \n"
      " ite eq                                                    \n"
      " mrseq r0, msp                                             \n"
      " mrsne r0, psp                                             \n"
      " ldr r1, [r0, #24]                                         \n"
      " ldr r2, SP_ADDRESS_CONST                                  \n"
      " bx r2                                                     \n"
      " SP_ADDRESS_CONST: .word getRegistersFromStack             \n"
  );
}

void my_assert(int exp) {
  if(!exp) {
    // here set exception (for debug purposes, i will set here hardfault active (ignore this please in the current discussion)
    NVIC_SetPendingIRQ(HardFault_IRQn);
  }
}

void main() {
  my_assert(0);
}
```

So here, it would show me that the function "my_assert()" is causing the issue, but this is not true, its the caller of "my_assert()".

**Questions:**

- Based on the link (https://www.silabs.com/content/usergenerated/asi/cloud/content/siliconlabs/en/community/mcu/32-bit/knowledge-base/jcr:content/content/primary/blog/debug_a_hardfault-78gc.social.0.10.html) i could correct the SP by "0x1C + sizeof(uint32_t)", is this correct?
- Is there a solution i can refactor this call from ASM to C? I am really not familiar with ASM and would strongly prefer a C implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this idea, unfortunately:

- The 'cause' of any kind of fault is difficult to determine and depends what you mean.  You claim that the `my_assert(0)` call is the cause of the fault in your example, but that's not really true; the cause is that the `my_assert` function itself raises a fault.  On the basis that a fault is not the intended behaviour (no sane implementation of `assert` would deliberately trigger a fault, surely) it's the `my_assert` function that needs debugging first.  In general, how is the fault handler supposed to know how far to unroll the stack?
- Stack unrolling is impossible anyway without significant extra knowledge.  How do you know what the stack frame of the function that raised the fault (`my_assert` in your example) looks like?  It could have stored hundreds of bytes of local variables on the stack prior to the fault being triggered.  How do you know what you're looking at?  Debuggers find this out by using debug information added to the compiled binary (e.g. using `gcc -g`).
- Even finding out where the fault was triggered is not always trivial.  Take the typical case of branching to an invalid address, perhaps due to a buffer overrun corrupting a return address on the stack.  The CPU will usually perform the branch, and then on attempting an instruction fetch will find that the address in question is not marked as executable and will fault.  On entry to handler mode the PC is stacked, but the stacked value is that of the invalid memory location, not of the code that attempted the branch to that location.  If you're very lucky the instruction that caused the branch was a `BL` or `BLX` (a call, effectively) and you'll find the intended return address in the stacked link register value.  But in my experience this is not common, and the best you'll get from the stacked `LR` is a vague clue about the last call that was made successfully prior to the fault, which could have been some time previously.

All in all, it's a nightmare.  This is what debuggers are for, honestly, and even then debugging faults can be very tricky.

In answer to your two specific questions:

1. Almost, maybe.  You mean 0x1C - there's no need to add an extra 4 bytes to that - and this will find the previous stack top only if you don't have a hardware FPU in use.  It should work on the Cortex-M3 but would be unreliable on the -M4F, for example.
2. Nope.  You're working with CPU implementation details here; you need controlled access to individual registers and there's no way C can give you that even using the CMSIS extensions.

Comment: i used 0x1C + 4 as the location 0x1C itself is still a 32bit wide variable, andtherefore i assumed 0x1C+4==length. the idea here is simpler than you might assume: my_assert has a known stack-usage, therefore, if i let the assert function set the exception (not hardfault, this was just an example), i can compensate the SP pointer correction back to the caller (main), as i know the top stack correction value (which is the function my_assert, remove that and i know the calling SP.

Comment: 0x1C is the number of items pushed during exception entry (without an FPU), so adding 0x1C to the stack pointer will restore it to its pre-exception location.

Comment: If your use-case is this specific, then I'm afraid I must repeat my assertion that "no sane implementation of `assert` would deliberately trigger a fault".  Why not use a software breakpoint or something in `my_assert`?  Why allow it to trigger a fault?

Comment: as a stack dump, in devices which are chip locked out in the field, and get a crash report over uart.

Comment: You don't need a fault to do that.  If you absolutely have to be in handler mode for some reason (can't imagine why you'd need it but anyway) you could use a SVC handler - indeed you use a macro to define your assert such that the `my_assert()` function doesn't even exist and the SVC handler will be invoked directly from the function that fails the assert.

Comment: haha yes good thinking, this is the standard default! #define assert(exp) if(!(exp) do something... the issue here is the amount of flash size used when you go with this kind of inline coding, where as when i make a actual function for this, i cut flash usage in half with the same functionality.

Comment: Flash usage is minimal really for a working assert implementation.  If you're really bothered about it, write a SVC handler and invoke it from the macro; the stacked value of PC will tell you the address of the line that invoked the handler.  The macro itself will expand to two instructions most of the time. `#define assert(exp) do {if !(exp) __svc(0);} while(0)`

Comment: no im sorry but this is not true. current example: if i do the macro, this gets inlined and brings my flash size up to >600kB, when i do however make an actual function for this and call the function instead an inline solution, i cut flash usage in half.

Comment: This is not the case.  Assuming that the target of the assert is an integral or pointer type and is already in a register, the macro I gave above will compile to a CMP, an ITE and a SVC.  A true function will compile to a MOV and a BL.  The difference is 4 bytes, and in addition the inline implementation will be considerably faster for the usual case when the assert succeeds.  If you're seeing 300kB differences in binary sizes then something else is changing (or you're issuing 75000 asserts)...